# is double and Double are different thing in dart and if it is can anyone explain me

Tags: flutter, dart, types, double, numeric

as we can see this gives an error that is telling that 0.0 is double that can't assigned to  Double datatype

[image]

then i tried Double as datatype and my code worked fine. but i don't understand what is going on here so can any one tell me what is going on here?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Double` comes from dart ffi,

> Represents a native 64 bit double in C.
> Double is not constructible in the Dart code and serves purely as marker in type signatures.

you mostly don't want it, use `double` instead.

Find more about [numbers in dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers) and [dart-ffi/Double](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-ffi/Double-class.html)